# combine only values across two columns in r

Tags: r

I have an issue with the following -

I have a dataframe as below:

I want to move the values from df$C into df$A.

I include df$B here as df$C only contains a value when df$B contains a string.

```
A      B       C

1234   NA      NA
NA     start   1500
2000   NA      NA
NA     end     2500
NA     NA      NA
NA     NA      NA
NA     start   3000
```

So, the desired result is as follows:

```
A     

1234  
1500     
2000   
2500   
NA     
NA     
3000
```

I'd really appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
df$A[is.na(df$A)] <- df$C[is.na(df$A)]
```

This is selecting from `df$A` those values where it is `NA`
and "fills" them with values from `df$C` at the same index.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ifelse`. Depending on how you want to process cases where you have non-`NA` values for both `A` and `C`, it will be one of:

```
df$A <- ifelse(is.na(df$A), df$C, df$A)
```

or

```
df$A <- ifelse(is.na(df$C), df$A, df$C)
```

---

A couple variants so you don't use too many `df$`:

```
df$A <- with(df, ifelse(is.na(A), C, A)
```

or

```
df <- transform(df, A = ifelse(is.na(A), C, A))
```